# Set string IP address using sharedpreferences into database connection class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

This is my connection class what i really want is how do i get the data in SharedPreference and set it into my String IPadd.

```
 public class ConnectionClass  {



    String IPadd ="192.168.254.117";


    String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+IPadd+"/dblight";
    String un = "light";
    String password = "12345";


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, password);


            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

My `SharedPreference` code to set the data

```
   try {
                         String strIP = ip.getText().toString();
                         SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                         editor.putString("name", strIP);
                         editor.commit();
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IP Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
```

Comment: I want to get the sharedPreference default value and set it into my String IPadd.. anyone can help??

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: it doesn't work.. Please anyone can help me??

Comment: Thank you very much Sir ..I've got it!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Add an Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();

private static MyApplication sInstance;

@Nullable
public static Context getAppContext() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    sInstance = this;
 }
}
```

2) Add the android:name line to your Manifest application tag

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

3) Inside your ConnectionClass class do this

```
IPadd = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(Filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name","defaultValue");
```

Comment: yes. but i want is how to set the sharedpreference value in my Connectionclass

Comment: i can retrieve it using textview in another class with layout but not in my connectionClass

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to pass a context variable and get the shared preferences from the context variable

Comment: how do i set it into my String IPadd?

Comment: Check last line

Comment: and how do i get the string value in this code MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(Filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name","defaultValue");?

Comment: This line returns a string. Assign it to a string variable like in the last line. THe getString method to be specific

Comment: i need String Value from sharedPreference and set it into my connection class as my IPAddress

Comment: Like ive been saying the last line does exactly that.

Comment: i'm using this code to read the data from the sharedpreference but my app got error //                SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences(Filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                String IP = "defaultValue";
//                IPadd = sharedPre.getString("name",IP);

Comment: Replace these two lines with the last line in the answer

Comment: you're getting an error because you are calling getSHaredPreferences directly. You need a context and that is exactly what i added in the last line.

Comment: this is my application class public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: that is your activity, not your application class

Comment: Should i create another class for that or im using my MainActivity Class??

Comment: im using my MainActivity Class in setting the data from the sharedPreference... should i use another class from your codes to do that??

Comment: Thank you sir.. Ive got it!! Salute!!

Comment: How did you achieve it in the end?